# next_posts_link not visible on first page

Tags: wp-query, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I cannot get the `<?php next_posts_link(); ?>` working in my custom post loop on the first page (
website.com/news).
The funny thing is that `<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>` does work on the second page (website.com/news/page/2/)

This is my query:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>News</h2>   

<?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

    <div class="row">   
        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4><a class="newslink" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                            <p class="card-text">
        <?php    
        the_excerpt(40,the_date('j F, Y','','<br>'));?>
                            </p>
                 </div>
            </div>
    </div>
        <?php 
        endwhile;
        ?>
<?php next_posts_link(); ?>
<?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
<?php  wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

As far as I am concerned i'm using the global var `$wp_query` so I'm not sure why it isnt working for the first page.

Comment: Why are you using a custom query at all?

Comment: Because I altered some of the standard items and some need future altering.Anysways if i use the wordpress example code as seen on:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I fixed it by using the a standard query:

```
    <?php 
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('showposts=6'.'&paged='.$paged);
?>

    <div class="row">   
        <?php while ($wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Seems like I wasn't using the global var in the first example -.-